# Why is this giving me an index error in python?

Tags: python, string

In the code below, s refers to a string (although I have tried converting it to a list and I still have the same problem).

```
s = "".join(s)
if s[-1] == "a":
    s += "gram"
```

I the last item in the string is the letter "a", then the program needs to add the string "gram" to the end of the string 's' represents.

e.g. input:

```
s = "insta"
```

output:

```
instagram
```

But I keep getting an `IndexError`, any ideas why?

Answer (score 7):

If `s` is empty string `s[-1]` causes `IndexError`:

```
>>> s = ""
>>> s[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Instead of `s[-1] == "a"`, you can use `s.endswith("a")`:

```
>>> s = ""
>>> s.endswith('a')
False
>>> s = "insta"
>>> s.endswith('a')
True
```

Comment: Its not an empty string because the user is prompted to enter a word, which is saved as the variable 's'

Comment: @HayleyvanWaas, Could you post the full traceback?

Comment: @HayleyvanWaas If the string is not empty then s[-1] would not raise `IndexError`.

Comment: @HayleyvanWaas: The `IndexError` is **only** raised if `s` is empty.

Answer (score 5):

If `s` is empty, there is *no* last letter to test:

```
>>> ''[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Use [`str.endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) instead:

```
if s.endswith('a'):
    s += 'gram'
```

`str.endswith()` does *not* raise an exception when the string is empty:

```
>>> 'insta'.endswith('a')
True
>>> ''.endswith('a')
False
```

Alternatively, using a slice would also work:

```
if s[-1:] == 'a':
```

as slices *always* return a result (at minimum an empty string) but `str.endswith()` is more self-evident as to what it does to the casual reader of your code.

Comment: You could also use a slice here, that'll return an empty string if the string is empty instead of raising an error

Comment: @Haidro: I am aware of that; but `str.endswith()` is self-documenting it's purpose here.